# "Bad Request" message in JWT OAuth authentication flow

Tags: docusignapi

i've followed all the instructions at the doc for generate JWT Token, but only receive "Bad Request" as response...

when i try to run eg-01-php-jwt the same occurs. i'm using DocuSign demo environment and simulating requests using Postman and curl

the steps i'm doing are:

1. generating authorization uri as https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&scope=signature%20impersonation&client_id=c0c3e3b4-87ec-46e6-afad-9f8cf9dda84c&redirect_uri=http://example.com/api/docusign/obtain-consent/callback
2. fill login and password for different docusign sandbox account
3. at the redirected uri i get the code parameter and decode at jwt.io, getting kid value from header
4. use kid value at sub to generate a new jwt token
5. sign jwt token with my private key
6. try to obtain access token and receive "Bad Request" as response message

my (*updated*) generated token is

```
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJjMGMzZTNiNC04N2VjLTQ2ZTYtYWZhZC05ZjhjZjlkZGE4NGMiLCJzdWIiOiI2ODE4NWZmMS00ZTUxLTRjZTktYWYxYy02ODk4MTIyMDMzMTciLCJpYXQiOjE1NTExMDA0MDksImV4cCI6MTU1MjEwMDQwOSwiYXVkIjoiYWNjb3VudC1kLmRvY3VzaWduLmNvbSIsInNjb3BlIjoic2lnbmF0dXJlIGltcGVyc29uYXRpb24ifQ.I1LhY77Rd0-op6UE3zUQvA5UxXIBzHUMyhhrwSN_TBv9ghiNAOr2aVz8Glf16bulkqSrE6A67h3DvL_VDm5NpNzcDQttjlf-CtlnBrjyt2w1niZkYnlmrUXW3SofDJkNHEj9-zQOa2XBrzTOLIhD6g2V0adBe45mwwGpMpOu0oPameUseDVEBeQ50mCZcyiMGYazEA0qeE9Ws9Rb7GxZxmOIZXaWirohmJhNfic5wHprJvA6tTwxai5-4xAwnhrjpsOWKoQRxXRkCKKcIIrKf8SEz4KOH2RCUBqMZRGys81CIDtowtLoDUeMCRKTaxnbrCFax4blJSZ8X3ptyneVpw
```

**UPDATE @ 2019-02-26**:

to achieve what i want i needed to complete the authorization code flow, get the user account id from step 4 (retrieve user data) and finally generate the jwt token with that info as *sub* at payload!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That assertion previously only included the `signature` scope. JWT Authentication requires `signature impersonation`.

Now that that has been updated, there are a couple of other possible issues:

- Invalid user ID. The JWT assertion requires an active User ID in the
  `sub` field. If the user is closed or the ID is incorrect this will
  fail.
- Invalid signature. The JWT assertion must be signed with an RSA
  private key associated with the `iss` / Client ID in use. If there
  are any invalid/encoding characters or trailing spaces, the signature
  may not be valid.

I'd recommend opening a case with DocuSign Support. On your side, you'll only receive the error `invalid_grant`. Support-side logging will have a more specific error. To assist with resolution, when opening a case please provide the following:

- Integrator key
- Demo account ID
- JWT Assertion
- `x-DocuSign-TraceToken` header value

Comment: i've tried that but had no success...
added the flow that i'm following when trying get the access token

Comment: the problem was on flow that i'd followed... updated the question with the correct flow! thanks!