# Docusign JWT Grant type "invalid_grant" response

Tags: docusignapi

We want to use our backend server to authenticate to docusign api (with admin consent) in order to create envelopes and prepare recipient views for the user to sign a document, and according to documentation, JSON Web Token (JWT) Grant seemed the way to go.

Following the documentation: https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/oauth2-jsonwebtoken, I've created a JWT with the following payload:

```
{
  "iss": "INTEGRATOR_KEY",
  "sub": "USER_ID",
  "iat": 1559295213,
  "exp": 1559298213,
  "aud": "account-d.docusign.com",
  "scope": "signature impersonation"
}
```

The JWT is constructed on jwt.io, well formed and I sent the encoded version along the request. I also followed the steps of obtaining consent and added permissions to the app as in the scope from the payload: "signature impersonation".

I also tried making sure, that `iat` is for example now and `exp` is not longer then one hour after `iat`.

I am making the request via postman before integrating into our app:

`POST https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token`

Headers:

`Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

And body:

```
grant_type: urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer
assertion: ENCODED_JWT_FROM_ABOVE
```

I don't see anything being outside of the descriptions given in the documentation but am continuously receiving the same error:

```
{
    "error": "invalid_grant"
}
```

I checked other questions related to the issue but didn't find anything which worked for me, also being for the JWT grant, some of them were issues with the requests, ie `headers`, some of them with code while integrating it into the app. Wanted to share the whole flow to make sure if for my case I am doing everything properly.

EDIT: Additional note: When I go to my docusign admin panel, and under `My Apps / Integration Keys` the app does not seem to be running, this is just an assumption according to the grey status indicator (while I saw for users it is green):
[image]

I am not sure if some additional configuration is required, if the demo app or trial account have some limitations so would appreciate any input. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, invalid_grant is an error that covers several possible failures. My recommendations for troubleshooting and next steps are over here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54836104/bad-request-message-in-jwt-oauth-authentication-flow/54836708#54836708

Answer (score -1):

Did you encrypt the JWT with your private key?

For `sub` did you use the user's guid (required) and not their email (won't work)?

Did you try using one of the [eg-01 series of code examples](https://github.com/docusign?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=eg-01&type=&language=) which use JWT Grant authentication?

Check out [Drew's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54836104/bad-request-message-in-jwt-oauth-authentication-flow/54836708#54836708) for additional ideas.